# My href links not working when contained within ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having a bizarre problem that I cannot figure out.  It is quite possible that I just do not know something fundamental which is the cause.  I really have no idea.  Anyway; I have a function on a page that uses mysql to look up divisions; then it has buttons for each division; and when you click each button; a team list for each division appears within a div container.  the buttons send a "div_id" value to the container.  The container then uses ajax to go back to mysql and then look up the teams for that division and output information on them.  This is all working.  But when I try and have the php file which is called from ajax list a simple href link for each team; the links do not appear.  It really seems that I cannot have href links present in the php file that is called by ajax.

I do not think I need to post all of the code for all the buttons and all that, if so please let me know; here is the script that does the ajax call on the php file:

```
<script>

 function MyRadFunction(DivId) {
 var answer = DivId;
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://jba.gtdsites.com/gscript3_links.php',
data: 'answer=' + answer,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(response) {
    $('#ajax_content').html(response);
}
});

    }
</script>
```

and here is the php file that is called:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
) {
    // AJAX request
    $answer = $_GET['answer'];
    $div_id=$answer;






    /* Connect to a mysql database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=gtdtables;host=gtdtables.db.1567753.hostedresource.com';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';


try {
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE div_id=$div_id";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $resultsg1)
{

$team_id=$resultsg1[team_id];
$team_name=$resultsg1[team_name];



echo "<a href='/team-schedules/?gc_start=2&team_id=<?php echo $team_id; ?>'><?php echo  $team_name; ?></a><br/>";

echo $team_name . "<br/>";
echo $team_id . "<br/>";
?>
Teams Page not link
<a href="/final-exam-1-intro/">Final Exam 1</a>

<a href="http://jba.gtdsites.com/team-schedules/?gc_start=2&team_id=<?php echo $team_id;  ?>"><?php echo $team_name; ?></a><br/>


<?php

}

}
?>
```

I echoes the team name and team id just fine; and where i just have it print text that works as well; but all of the html hyperlink stuff just does not appear; I tried a few different ways.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: don't post real credentials on SO

Comment: Hello Ghost; those are not real credentials; I changed them to fake ones; but if you have a better way to do this than me then I would love to hear your opinion...

Comment: just making sure, you didn't put a disclaimer anyway

Comment: ah - i see you just changed it to "username and password"; thanks for your input...

Comment: anyway, since you're using PDO why not use prepared statements, and try to explicitly put the expected value on the ajax as html, by the way you have typos on the indices inside the loop, is that loop working? you don't have a fetch

Comment: I am just learning to do PDO; and have not learned how to use a prepared statement to do "fetchall" so I can loop through each team and get team name and team id; I found that simple query that does it and works with PDO; I tried and tried to do it with the prepared statement and could not get it to work.  But the loop is working fine; it outputs the team name and the team id with no problem (just echoes them; but the hyperlinks that use the same stuff do not work)

Comment: just try to explicitly put `dataType: html,` and check

Comment: Hello Ghost I added that to the Ajax call and that did not change anything; I also added that to the question above so you can see how i did it...

Comment: whats not appearing? the team name links or the final exam?

Comment: you can see it execute here:  http://jba.gtdsites.com/team-schedules/

Comment: everything that is not a hyperlink shows and all hyperlinks are not there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is kinda funny, but here it is, upon examining the [site](http://jba.gtdsites.com/team-schedules/), on the network tab the markup built from PHP is rendered correctly. But the thing is:

The CSS is the problem:

```
a { color: #fff; }
```

Your text color on the links are white. Therefore its not seen, but its there, just change it accordingly.

```
a { color: #000; } /** or which color you want **/
```

And in your PHP, properly concatenate the values:

```
echo "<a href='/team-schedules/?gc_start=2&team_id=".$team_id."'>".$team_name."</a><br/>";
```

Important note: Don't just directly use variables inside your statements, use prepared statements to produce safer queries. [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a tutorial for that.

Comment: thanks so much Ghost; you caught it!  (and yes it is funny; my bad!)